# combine prediction output of one frozen model to predict and then use those predictions as a loss for the model which i am training?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to combine the prediction output of one frozen model in a training phase of another.

I have tried using different graph sessions but it resets the default graph in the training phase.

```
predictions = model1.model(input1, input2, mode)
predictions2 = model2.predict(predictions)

loss1 = mean_squared_error(predictions, labels)
loss2 = mean_squared_error(input2, predictions2)

total_loss = loss1+loss2

optimizer.minimize(total_loss)
```

> ValueError: Tensor Tensor("output_layer/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 100), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out!

In the tensorflow's estimator framework, load the model in the 'model_fn' of your Estimator space with the attribute:
'keras_model.trainable=False'

eg snippet:

```
def model_fn(inputs):
    .......
    #some operations

    .......
    model2=load_model('frozen_model.h5')
    model2.trainable=False
    model2.summary()
    predictions= model2(inputs=predictions)
```